# Java loop breaking at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, runtime

My program seems to go into some infinite loop, but isn't giving any heap error or anything. Still I would like to know where the loop is.

I am using Eclipse and running in normal mode (not in debug mode). Also my program is nondeterministic, so I can't run it again to recreate the infinite loop.

Is there a way to find the infinite loop?

Comment: yeah there is a way to find it, but not for us, only for you (without any code)

Comment: Post your code snippet, if possible.

Comment: You need to take a stack dump when your code is in the long loop.  Note: just because a loop takes a long time doesn't make it infinite.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run in debug mode? Then you can just pause the program and examine the stack.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wait until the infinite loop shows up, then use [`jstack -l <pid>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) to get a stack dump, and analyze that.

With a modicum of luck, this should suggest some lines of further inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You could run your application under profiler [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) It's help you to find your infinity loop (analize iterations, process loading and so on parameters)